# How to compute the 99% percent quantile of a normal variable: Scilab

Tags: normal-distribution, scilab

I am trying to write a function that computes the quantile of the normal distribution using the function cdfnor.
for example

> alpha= cdfnor("PQ",x,0,1)

anyone could help me to derive from this function the 99 percent quantile for example. how should I define the x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `perctl` function is what you are looking for...